# Injecting a list of dependencies with multiple interfaces in autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, code-injection

I have this class where I'm trying to inject a list of qualifying objects:

```
public class BlingDispatcher : IBlingDispatcher
{
    readonly IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler> _domainEventHandlers;

    #region IBlingDispatcher Members

    public BlingDispatcher(IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler> domainEventHandlers)
    {
        _domainEventHandlers = domainEventHandlers;
    }
}
```

Classes like this get injected here and work great:

```
public class NotifyFrontEndSomethingHappened : IDomainEventHandler<SomethingHappened>
{
    private readonly IFrontEndNotifier _frontEndNotifier;

    public NotifyFrontEndAfterSomethingHappened(IFrontEndNotifier frontEndNotifier)
    {
        _frontEndNotifier = frontEndNotifier;
    }
 }
```

Classes like this do not:

```
public class NotifyFrontEndAfterEvent : IDomainEventHandler<SomethingHappened>,
                                        IDomainEventHandler<SomethingElseHappened>,
                                        IDomainEventHandler<MoreThingsHappened>,
                                        IDomainEventHandler<AndYetMoreThings>
{
    readonly IFrontEndNotifier _frontEndNotifier;

    public void Handle(SomethingHappened @event)
    {
        _frontEndNotifier.Notify(@event, @event.CommanderId);
    }

 ...

 }
```

How can I get classes with multiple interfaces to be injected by autofac as well?

**EDIT**

More information:

```
public interface IDomainEventHandler
{
}

public interface IDomainEventHandler<in T> : IBlingHandler<T>, IDomainEventHandler
{

}

public interface IBlingHandler<in T>
{
    void Handle(T @event);
}
```

Registering like this in bootstapper:

```
container.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.Name.StartsWith("IBlingHandler")))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Comment: How are you registering your types?

Comment: Do you have two interfaces: `IDomainEventHandler` and `IDomainEventHandler<T>`? in your first code snippet, you have `IDomainEventHandler`. In the other snippets, you have `IDomainEventHandler <T>`

Comment: here's how I register them: container.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
                .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.Name.StartsWith("IBlingHandler")))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();

Comment: and yes i do have 2 interfaces...more like 3: public interface IDomainEventHandler
    {
    }
   
    public interface IDomainEventHandler<in T> : IBlingHandler<T>, IDomainEventHandler
    {

    }

Comment: here's the blinghandler: public interface IBlingHandler<in T>
  {
    void Handle(T @event);
  }

Comment: So, you want NotifyFrontEndAfterEvent to be injected into BlingDispatcher?

Comment: yes. For some reason it's not working. All the others that only implement one interface get injected.

Comment: This cannot work since IDomainEventHandler<T> is a totally different type than IDomainEventHandler.

Comment: It shouldn't even work for NotifyFrontEndSomethingHappened.

Comment: It does work for NotifyFrontEndSomethingHappened. IDomainEventHandler<T> implements IDomainEventHandler

Comment: sorry, I didn't see that

Comment: Np. Added the interfaces and registering to answer to clarify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90061/discussion-between-yacoub-massad-and-richard).